# Custom SOAP response of ASMX service

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying to implement a custom SOAP response of the legacy web service.

At the moment it has the following format:

```
<ServiceResponse>
    <ServiceResult>some return value</ServiceResult>
</ServiceResponse>
```

I need to add string value like this:

```
<ServiceResponse>NEW VALUE
    <ServiceResult>some return value</ServiceResult>
</ServiceResponse>
```

I'm not sure if it is a good idea at all? Is this SOAP xml valid? If yes, how it can be accomplished?

Any suggestion or idea would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to insert custom values in the SOAP response? Why not using a custom HTTP header instead? It will be easier to implement and won't break existing clients. Also why not simply adding a new property to the response object which could hold the value?

Comment: I know that there are many ways to implement it in a better way, but please keep in mind that this is a legacy system and this fix is actually needed for an external system which uses this service. Thank for a quick reply.

Comment: I've never seen a SOAP service return data like that. Legacy or not, I think you may have misunderstood. Can you post the part of the schema that describes that data?

Answer (score 1):

That xml *is*<strike>n't</strike> valid, in a node you *can*<strike>'t</strike> have both text and a child node like you have there.

If you're writing your webservice in .NET I would advise you construct a `Serializable` class that represents the data structure that you want to return, when you create your webservice it will automatically get converted into a valid soap data structure. You will also be able to see the definition of your response when you browse the WSDL at Service.asmx?wsdl.

If you'd like some more info on SOAP checkout the specification at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part1-20070427/#soapenv)

**Edit:** Removed false claim as pointed out by marc_s

Comment: Actually: yes, you **can have** "mixed content" inside an XML node - both text and other tags. That's what XHTML is all about.... and yes, you can even express this in XML schema and validate it! (so it **IS** valid) - see [Complex types with mixed content](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp)

Comment: @marc_s: I stand corrected! Thanks for the link, I didn't know that.